# Which technology should I use for a mobile web app: HTML5 or jQuery Mobile?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, mobile-website

I have been assigned to build a mobile web application. I have found two ways to develop that (there might be hundred other ways to do that, but I am aware of these two): jQuery Mobile and HTML 5.

Which one should I use? The application will be a normal web app, like a shopping web app or a user management system.

I am looking for compatibility in different phones and great UI with fast processing.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite Thanks for correcting it, now it make sense. It happened because I am not a native english speaker. :-\

Comment: jQuery Mobile sites are HTML5 sites. Those aren't competing technologies.

Comment: @Chris: no problem at all, you’re very welcome! I hope other people do the same for me when we all have to post to Stack Overflow in Chinese :)

Comment: jquery mobile is good and improved a lot now though there are still few limitations but it also depends on what exactly u r looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, the ways I know is JQuery mobile and HTML 5.
>
> Which one should I use?

It's not a case of using one or the other - you use both to create a solution.

HTML5 provides the framework to present your content, whether it is text, images, video, audio, or any mixture of the above.

jQuery (Original or Mobile) is used for "Progressive Enhancement", that is to provide additional functionality, features or flair to the HTML5 framework.

To ensure the best compatibility across the majority of devices, you want to have a website which is usable without the jQuery enhancement. Then, once you have that, you can use jQuery (and/or standard javascript) to add the "nice-to-have"s, like animations, AJAX interactions, geolocation, etc.

Comment: “To ensure the best compatibility across the majority of devices, you want to have a website which is usable without the jQuery enhancement.” — *Really*? Is there going to be an appreciable number of people attempting to use this shopping/user-management app on devices that don’t support JavaScript?

Comment: @Paul: Admittedly, the proportions are shifting towards fewer and fewer people browsing without javascript on, but that being said, I think it is still a good practice in that it ensures that websites are crawlable and also means that a website is less likely to suffer from major degradation when visited via a slow or unstable connection. Even with faster connections, a flash of unstyled or incomplete content before the javascript enhancements kick in can upset some visitors/clients.

Comment: web*sites*, sure. For a web app, crawlability may not be important. And if someone’s on a slow connection, a pure HTML-based app, which requires round-trips to the server, could be slower than an app that uses a bit of JavaScript.

Comment: @Paul: I get your point, but I stand by the statement. Especially so as the project I am currently on is HTML5/jQuery within an iPad App Container, and it still rings true. Even with the resources being stored locally within the device the (minor) delays in rendering javascript-created/controlled elements means that the HTML has to be complete first and foremost and any enhancements/interaction on top of that cannot be critical/essential for the user.

Comment: oh, sure — if you take the server out of the equation, then less JavaScript mean a more responsive app. I’m not sure that really still qualifies as a web app though. (I’m assuming your app doesn’t call back to a web server for functionality — apologies if I’ve misunderstood.)

Answer (score 2):

[Lucanos](/questions/6690058/which-technology-should-i-use-for-a-mobile-web-app-html5-or-jquery-mobile/6690129#6690129) is right in the sense that HTML and jQuery aren’t alternatives. (Browsers display HTML, and then you write JavaScript — possibly using a framework like jQuery — to manipulate that HTML in custom ways where necessary.)

However, if you‘re using “HTML5” in the Apple sense of the word (i.e. to describe HTML5, CSS3, and browser-specific extensions to CSS), then there are some choices to make — e.g. some WebKit-based mobile browsers support CSS animations, which should perform faster than JavaScript animations.

I’m not familiar with jQuery Mobile — it might well use CSS animations when they’re supported, and simulate them when they’re not, meaning you get wider compatibility without much runtime performance cost.

But for mobile, personally I think you’re better off picking the most popular platforms (i.e. iOS and Android), and writing to their capabilities, without bothering with a framework like jQuery Mobile. That way you serve most of the market with less effort (and thus serve them better), rather than making everyone download jQuery Mobile just to serve a few older phones that’ll get binned in a year or two anyway.

**Disclaimer: this depends entirely on your target market. If they all use old phones, write to the capabilities of those phones.**